# send delegate uitableview to other view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have an uiTableviewController and A uiNavigationController. Can i implement the delegate DidselectRowAtIndexPath from the UITableViewController in the uiNavigationController so when i select a row in the table there performs an action in the uinavigationcontroller?

Comment: i don't think that's usually how it works--`UINavigationController` isn't usually subclassed. What action do you want to take? If it's a navigation action, your view controller can push a new view controller. If it's an app-wide action, you can send the action to your app delegate from your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass UINavigationController and implement there the UITableViewDelegate, the UIViewController responsable of the tableView should be the delegate, and you can just perporm your operation on the navigationController just referting to it from the viewController that implemente the tableView delegate.

Just to give you an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RSSItem *item = [_feed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (item.link) {

        WebviewViewController *webViewController = [[WebviewViewController alloc] initWebViewWithLink:item.link title:item.title];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the delegate programatically to different viewController over code, it is much cleaner.

```
    uitableView.delegate = uinavigationviewcontroller.
```

But I would implement both datasource and delegate in first view controller and write a custom delegate in the second viewController(which the navigationViewController in your case) and call it on didSelectRowAtIndex: from the first one.